# AVFoundation - Merge multiple video - add animation in between videos

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avmutablecomposition

I am trying to merge images and video clips together. I kept an option to add animation in between videos and images. There has few options like fade-in, fade-out, rotate, slide-up, slide-down, left, right etc. For images I am able to add animation, but how to add animation for video? Specifically when a video clip is completed and another video clip is going to start that time I want to add animations. Now my merging functionality is working well. Only to add the animation in between the videos.

I have tried with:

```
instruction.setOpacityRamp(fromStartOpacity: <#T##Float#>, toEndOpacity: <#T##Float#>, timeRange: <#T##CMTimeRange#>)
```

but this option only showing fade-in/ fade-out effect. But other custom animation options where to add those effect and how?

Here is me source code for merging. Many dependant functions are there in the code. But I have posted only merging functionality code. I have commented with `//HERE TO ADD THE ANIMATION`. So that you can directly reach that point where I am trying to add animations.

```
func merge(allAssets: [MovieAssetPresentable], isHDR: Bool, success: @escaping (URL?) -> (Void), progress: @escaping (CGFloat) -> (Void), failed: @escaping (String?) -> (Void)) {
    cancelExport()
    let defaultSize = isHDR ? self.videoOutputResolution.HD : self.videoOutputResolution.lowQuality
    let videoPresetName = self.getPresetName(resolution: defaultSize)

    self.mergeSuccess = success
    self.mergeError = failed
    self.mergeProgress = progress

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()

    let mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()

    var layerInstructions = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction]()

    guard let urlVideoForBackground = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "black", withExtension: "mov") else {
        self.mergeError("Need black background video !")
        return
    }

    let assetForBackground = AVAsset(url: urlVideoForBackground)

    let trackForBackground = assetForBackground.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first

    //Set output size
    var outputSize = CGSize.zero

    for asset in allAssets.filter({$0.assetType! == .video}) {
        guard let videoAsset = asset.asset else { continue }

        // Get video track
        guard let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { continue }

        let assetInfo = self.orientationFromTransform(videoTrack.preferredTransform)

        var videoSize = videoTrack.naturalSize

        if assetInfo.isPortrait == true {
            videoSize.width = videoTrack.naturalSize.height
            videoSize.height = videoTrack.naturalSize.width
        }

        if videoSize.height > outputSize.height {
            outputSize = CGSize(width: defaultSize.width, height: ((videoSize.height / videoSize.width) * defaultSize.width))
        }
    }

    if outputSize == CGSize.zero {
        outputSize = defaultSize
    }

    debugPrint("OUTPUT SIZE: \(outputSize)")
    let layerContentsGravity = VideoSettings.shared.fetchVideoFitClips()
    var layerImages = [CALayer]()

    var insertTime = CMTime.zero

    var audioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters]()


    // Init Video layer
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
    videoLayer.contentsGravity = layerContentsGravity

    let parentlayer = CALayer()
    parentlayer.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: outputSize.width, height: outputSize.height)
    parentlayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)


    for asset in allAssets.filter({$0.assetType! == .image || $0.assetType! == .video}) {
        //Video speed level
        let videoSpeed = Double(asset.videoSpeedLevel!)
        if asset.assetType! == .video {
            //Video asset
            let ast = asset.asset!
            let duration = asset.endTime! - asset.beginTime! //ast.duration

            //Create AVMutableCompositionTrack object
            guard let track = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                             preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)) else {
                                                                self.mergeError("Unable to create track.")
                                                                continue
            }

            //Add original video sound track
            let originalSoundTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack?
            if asset.asset!.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).count > 0 {
                originalSoundTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
                do {
                    try originalSoundTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: asset.beginTime ?? CMTime.zero, duration: duration), of: ast.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0], at: insertTime)
                } catch {
                    self.mergeError("Unable to create original audio track.")
                    continue
                }
                //Set video original sound track speed
                originalSoundTrack?.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: asset.beginTime ?? CMTime.zero, duration: duration), toDuration: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(Double(duration.value) * videoSpeed), timescale: duration.timescale))

                let audioInputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: originalSoundTrack)
                audioInputParams.setVolume(asset.videoOriginalVolume!, at: CMTime.zero)
                audioInputParams.trackID = originalSoundTrack?.trackID ?? kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid
                audioMixInputParameters.append(audioInputParams)
            }

            //Set time range
            do {
                try track.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: asset.beginTime ?? CMTime.zero, duration: duration),
                                          of: ast.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0],
                                          at: insertTime)
            } catch let err {
                self.mergeError("Failed to load track: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                continue
            }
            //Set video speed
            track.scaleTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: asset.beginTime ?? CMTime.zero, duration: duration), toDuration: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(Double(duration.value) * videoSpeed), timescale: duration.timescale))

            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)


            let instruction = self.videoCompositionInstruction(track, asset: ast, outputSize: outputSize)
            //                let instruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: t, asset: ast, standardSize: outputSize, atTime: insertTime)
            instruction.setOpacity(0.0, at: insertTime)

            //HERE TO ADD THE ANIMATION

            layerInstructions.append(instruction)
        } else {
            //Image data
            let videoCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video,
                                                                       preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

            let defaultImageTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.endTime!) - CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.beginTime!)
            let duration = CMTime.init(seconds:defaultImageTime, preferredTimescale: assetForBackground.duration.timescale)
            do {
                try videoCompositionTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: duration),
                                                           of: trackForBackground!,
                                                           at: insertTime)
            }
            catch {
                self.mergeError("Background time range error")
            }

            guard let image = UIImage(data: asset.imageData!) else { continue }

            // Create Image layer
            let imageLayer = CALayer()
            imageLayer.frame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: outputSize)
            imageLayer.contents = image.cgImage
            imageLayer.opacity = 0
            imageLayer.contentsGravity = layerContentsGravity

            self.setOrientation(image: image, onLayer: imageLayer)

            // Add Fade in & Fade out animation
            let fadeInAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
            fadeInAnimation.duration = 1
            fadeInAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
            fadeInAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
            fadeInAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            fadeInAnimation.beginTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(insertTime) == 0 ? 0.05: CMTimeGetSeconds(insertTime)
            fadeInAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            imageLayer.add(fadeInAnimation, forKey: "opacityIN")

            let fadeOutAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "opacity")
            fadeOutAnimation.duration = 1
            fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
            fadeOutAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 0)
            fadeOutAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
            fadeOutAnimation.beginTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration))
            fadeOutAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
            imageLayer.add(fadeOutAnimation, forKey: "opacityOUT")

            layerImages.append(imageLayer)

            // Increase the insert time
            insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, duration)
        }
    }


    // Add Image layers
    for layer in layerImages {
        parentlayer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    //Add Water mark if Subscription not activated
    if !AddManager.shared.hasActiveSubscription {

        let imglogo = UIImage(named: "watermark")
        let waterMarklayer = CALayer()
        waterMarklayer.contents = imglogo?.cgImage
        let sizeOfWaterMark = Utility.getWaterMarkSizeWithVideoSize(videoSize: outputSize, defaultSize: waterMarkSize)
        debugPrint("sizeOfWaterMark=\(sizeOfWaterMark)")
        waterMarklayer.frame = CGRect(x: outputSize.width - (sizeOfWaterMark.width+10), y: 5, width: sizeOfWaterMark.width, height: sizeOfWaterMark.height)
        waterMarklayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
        waterMarklayer.opacity = 1.0
        parentlayer.addSublayer(waterMarklayer)
    }

    mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: CMTime.zero, duration: insertTime)
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructions
    mainInstruction.backgroundColor = VideoSettings.shared.fetchVideoBackgroundColor().color.cgColor

    let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
    mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    mainComposition.renderSize = outputSize
    mainComposition.renderScale = 1.0
    mainComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentlayer)

    for audioAsset in allAssets.filter({$0.assetType! == .audio}) {
        //NOTE: If you have requirement to increase/ decrease audio fade-in fade-out effect time, please modify fadeInFadeOutEffectTiming variable as second
        let fadeInFadeOutEffectTiming = Double(3) //seconds

        let volumeLevel = audioAsset.audioVolumeLevel!
        let isFadeIn = audioAsset.audioFadeInEffect!
        let isFadeOut = audioAsset.audioFadeOutEffect!
        var audioBeginTime = audioAsset.beginTime!
        var audioEndTime = audioAsset.endTime!
        var audioTrackTime = audioAsset.audioTrackStartTime!
        var trimmedAudioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(audioEndTime, audioBeginTime)

        //If audio starting position (second) is greater than equals to zero (in order to video length)

        if CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime)) >= 0 {
            //If audio starting position (second) more than video length, i.e. total video length is 20 second, but audio starting position is from 24 seconds, we sould not add the audio
            if CMTimeCompare(CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime), insertTime) == 1 {
                trimmedAudioDuration = CMTime.zero
            } else {
                //If audio start position (seconds) + crop length is exceed total video length, we should add only the part within the video
                if CMTimeCompare(CMTimeAdd(CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime), trimmedAudioDuration), insertTime) == 1 {
                    audioTrackTime = CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime)
                    trimmedAudioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(insertTime, audioTrackTime)
                } else {
                    audioTrackTime = CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime)
                }
            }
        }
            //If audio start time is in negative (second)
        else {
            //If audio crop length is in negative (second)
            if CMTimeCompare(CMTimeAdd(CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, audioBeginTime), trimmedAudioDuration), CMTime.zero) == -1 {
                trimmedAudioDuration = CMTime.zero
            } else {
                audioBeginTime = CMTime(seconds: abs(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioTrackTime)), preferredTimescale: audioTrackTime.timescale)
                audioTrackTime = CMTime.zero
                trimmedAudioDuration = CMTimeSubtract(audioEndTime, audioBeginTime)
                if CMTimeCompare(trimmedAudioDuration, insertTime) == 1 {
                    trimmedAudioDuration = insertTime
                }
            }
        }

        if trimmedAudioDuration != CMTime.zero {
            audioEndTime = CMTimeAdd(audioTrackTime, trimmedAudioDuration)
            let audioTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
            do {
                try audioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: audioBeginTime , duration: trimmedAudioDuration),
                                                of: audioAsset.asset!.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.audio)[0] ,
                                                at: audioTrackTime)
                let audioInputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)

                var effectTime = CMTime(seconds: fadeInFadeOutEffectTiming, preferredTimescale: 600)
                if CMTimeCompare(trimmedAudioDuration, CMTimeMultiply(effectTime, multiplier: 2)) == -1 {
                    effectTime = CMTime(seconds: CMTimeGetSeconds(trimmedAudioDuration) / 2, preferredTimescale: 600)
                }

                //Fade in effect
                audioInputParams.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: isFadeIn ? 0 : volumeLevel, toEndVolume: volumeLevel, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: audioTrackTime, duration: effectTime))
                //Fade out effect
                audioInputParams.setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: volumeLevel, toEndVolume: isFadeOut ? 0 : volumeLevel, timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTimeSubtract(audioEndTime, effectTime), duration: effectTime))

                audioInputParams.trackID = audioTrack?.trackID ?? kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid
                audioMixInputParameters.append(audioInputParams)
            } catch {
                print("Failed to load Audio track")
            }
        }
    }

    // 4 - Get path
    guard let url = Utility.createFileAtDocumentDirectory(name: "mergeVideo-\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).mp4") else {
        debugPrint("Unable to file at document directory")
        return
    }

    // 5 - Create Exporter
    self.exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: mixComposition, presetName: videoPresetName)
    guard let exp = self.exporter else {
        debugPrint("Unable to export.")
        return
    }
    let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
    audioMix.inputParameters = audioMixInputParameters
    exp.outputURL = url
    exp.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exp.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exp.videoComposition = mainComposition
    exp.audioMix = audioMix

    //self.viewPieProgress.setProgress(0.0, animated: false)
    //viewPieProgress.isHidden = isHDR

    //timer for progress
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateExportingProgress(timer:)), userInfo: exp, repeats: true)

    // 6 - Perform the Export
    exp.exportAsynchronously() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.exportDidFinish(exp)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many options but nothing meets my requirement. Please help me out.

If you required any other information from me, please feel free to comment on this post.

Thanks in advance.